# Eliminar un elemento de un arreglo de objetos en base a un atributo del objeto JAVA

Tags: java, array, objeto, delete

Necesito eliminar un objeto de un elemento de objetos en base a su atributo, tengo mi arreglo de Autos, entre sus atributos está el número de serie, quisiera saber que método puedo implementar para eliminar ese objeto en base al número de serie que se introduzca. No debo ocupar librerías externas.

Mi arreglo de autos junto con su método de añadir autos:

```
Auto autos[] = new Auto[1];
public void darDeAlta(int serie, String marca, String modelo, int año, double precioDeLista, String color, String status, String motor) {
    Auto auto = new Auto(serie, marca, modelo, año, precioDeLista, color, status, motor);
    if (autos[0] == null) {

        autos[0] = auto;

    } else {
        Auto[] autosAuxiliar = new Auto[autos.length + 1];
        autosAuxiliar[autosAuxiliar.length - 1] = auto;

        for (int i = 0; i < autos.length; i++) {
            autosAuxiliar[i] = autos[i];
        }
         autos = autosAuxiliar;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? En SO no son de buen agrado las preguntas del tipo: esta es mi tarea ¿Cómo la hago? Vuelve con algo que hayas intentado y entonces te ayudaremos.

Answer (score 0):

Claro! Solo hace falta seguir la misma logica que aplicaste al añadir un nuevo auto.

Pero ahora en lugar de crear el arreglo aux mas grande (+1) creas uno mas chico (-1)..

Hay dos indices **int i = 0, j= 0**, uno para recorrer todo el array de autos y otro para recorrer el array auxiliar (que solo aumenta si el serial no coincide)

Ademas hay una bool **encontrado**, es opcional, pero te ayuda a que no haya error si de casualidad no encuentra el numero de serie o si esta duplicado

```
    public void darDeBaja(int serie){
        Auto[] autosAuxiliar = new Auto[autos.length - 1];
        boolean encontrado = false;
        
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < autos.length; i++) {
            Auto auto = autos[i];

            if(auto.serie != serie || encontrado){
                autosAuxiliar[j] = autos[i];
                j++;
            } else {
                encontrado = true;
            }
            
        }

        if(encontrado){
            autos = autosAuxiliar;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, José; funcionó de maravilla, no se me habría ocurrido la lógica a la inversa de añadir auto.

Comment: Excelente! para eso estamos